# Regular Expressions in C# running slowly

Tags: c#, regex, performance

I have been doing a little work with regex over the past week and managed to make a lot of progress, however, I'm still fairly n00b.  I have a regex written in C#:

```
string isMethodRegex = 
    @"\b(public|private|internal|protected)?\s*(static|virtual|abstract)?"+
    @"\s*(?<returnType>[a-zA-Z\<\>_1-9]*)\s(?<method>[a-zA-Z\<\>_1-9]+)\s*\"+
    @"((?<parameters>(([a-zA-Z\[\]\<\>_1-9]*\s*[a-zA-Z_1-9]*\s*)[,]?\s*)+)\)";
IsMethodRegex = new Regex(isMethodRegex);
```

For some reason, when calling the regular expression IsMethodRegex.IsMatch() it hangs for 30+ seconds on the following string:

```
"\t * Returns collection of active STOP transactions (transaction type 30) "
```

Does anyone how the internals of Regex works and why this would be so slow on matching this string and not others. I have had a play with it and found that if I take out the * and the parenthesis then it runs fine. Perhaps the regular expression is poorly written?

Any help would be so greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried compiling the regex?  One of the constructor overloads provides this ability.

Comment: @Steve: I just tested myself and after compiling it still takes a long time.  I can reproduce the long time on my own machine in LinqPad.

Comment: I know this is beside the point but your regex looks very brittle to me. Somehow I think performance is the least of your problems.

Comment: Hey Chris, how would you go about writting it?

Comment: How about explaining the actual problem you are attempting to solve?

Comment: ok, this particular problem is to scan a code file (various different languages, c# Java and VB) and find the method calls, class names and namespace.  I did look for some code parsers but could not find anything recent (that handle things like generics) so I decided to write my own.  This regex is the one for finding method calls in c#, they all seem to work fine but as i have been testing it more and more I'm finding that the Method Regex is not very fast, thoughts?

Comment: It's equally valid to state `static private` instead of `private static`. I'm sure there are other issues. The problem with using an expression this "comprehensive" is that it makes an unmaintainable mess, is frequestly wrong and it is not practical to embody in it the rules of a language specification. Simply validating an email address with regex uses a pattern considerably longer than what you have. I'd pay close attention to @ChaosPandion, because I suspect he's right.

Comment: Take a look at this ( http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html ) for sh*ts and giggles...

Comment: This might provide some insight into what to look out for: http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**: I think the performance issue comes in the way `<parameters>` matching group is done.  I have rearranged to match a first parameter, then any number of successive parameters, or optionally none at all.  Also I have changed the `\s*` between parameter type and name to `\s+` (I think this was responsible for a LOT of backtracking because it allows no spaces, so that `object` could match as `obj` and `ect` with `\s*` matching no spaces) and it seems to run a lot faster:

```
string isMethodRegex = 
    @"\b(public|private|internal|protected)?\s*(static|virtual|abstract)?"+
    @"\s*(?<returnType>[a-zA-Z\<\>_1-9]*)\s*(?<method>[a-zA-Z\<\>_1-9]+)\s*\"+
    @"((?<parameters>((\s*[a-zA-Z\[\]\<\>_1-9]*\s+[a-zA-Z_1-9]*\s*)"+
    @"(\s*,\s*[a-zA-Z\[\]\<\>_1-9]*\s+[a-zA-Z_1-9]*\s*)*\s*))?\)";
```

---

**EDIT**: As duly pointed out by @Dan, the following is simply because the Regex can exit early.

This is indeed a really bizarre situation, but if I remove the two optional matching at the beginning (for public/private/internal/protected and static/virtual/abstract) then it starts to run almost instantaneously again:

```
string isMethodRegex = 
    @"\b(public|private|internal|protected)\s*(static|virtual|abstract)"+
    @"(?<returnType>[a-zA-Z\<\>_1-9]*)\s(?<method>[a-zA-Z\<\>_1-9]+)\s*\"+
    @"((?<parameters>(([a-zA-Z\[\]\<\>_1-9]*\s*[a-zA-Z_1-9]*\s*)[,]?\s*)+)\)";
var IsMethodRegex = new Regex(isMethodRegex);

string s = "\t * Returns collection of active STOP transactions (transaction type 30) ";

Console.WriteLine(IsMethodRegex.IsMatch(s));
```

Technically you could split into four separate Regex's for each possibility to deal with this particular situation.  However, as you attempt to deal with more and more complicated scenarios, you will likely run into this performance issue again and again, so this is probably not the ideal approach.

Comment: The result of this is a 'false', correct?  It can exclude the match immediately because it doesn't begin with 'p' or 'i', so it's a trivial search.

Comment: @Dan: Indeed you are correct.  I suspect it has something to do with the way the `<parameters>` part is done.

Answer (score 3):

I changed some 0-or-more (*) matchings with 1-or-more (+), where I *think* it makes sense for your regex (it's more suitable to Java and C# than to VB.NET):

```
string isMethodRegex =
  @"\b(public|private|internal|protected)?\s*(static|virtual|abstract)?" +
  @"\s*(?<returnType>[a-zA-Z\<\>_1-9]+)\s+(?<method>[a-zA-Z\<\>_1-9]+)\s+\" +
  @"((?<parameters>(([a-zA-Z\[\]\<\>_1-9]+\s+[a-zA-Z_1-9]+\s*)[,]?\s*)+)\)";
```

It's fast now.

Please check if it still returns the result you expect.

For some background on bad regexes, look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReDoS).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried compiling your Regex?

```
string pattern = @"\b[at]\w+";
RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled;
string text = "The threaded application ate up the thread pool as it executed.";
MatchCollection matches;

Regex optionRegex = new Regex(pattern, options);
Console.WriteLine("Parsing '{0}' with options {1}:", text, options.ToString());
// Get matches of pattern in text
matches = optionRegex.Matches(text);
// Iterate matches
for (int ctr = 1; ctr <= matches.Count; ctr++)
   Console.WriteLine("{0}. {1}", ctr, matches[ctr-1].Value);
```

Then the Regular Expression is only slow on the first execution.

Comment: We already tried, it made no difference.  In fact there was an answer that said the same thing awhile ago that the author deleted.